# What's the convention on coffee regarding signatures in questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

The [convention on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/7872) is that signatures in Q & A aren't required, or desired:

> We don't want to clutter up question pages with a lot of redundant signature blocks and taglines and so forth. While these are common on forums, questions and answers on Stack Exchange should contain only relevant content.
>
> Please use your built in profile, avatar, and username as your signature; that's what they are there for, and every post you make is already "signed" this way!

I recently [proposed an edit](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4426) to an answer which corrected a spelling mistake *and* removed the posters signature. This was approved by one user and then rejected by the author of the answer with the (canned) reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Putting aside the fact that it's a wildly inappropriate reason to select when rejecting the specific edits made, what is the convention/policy on coffee regarding having / removing signatures from Q&A? Is there one that differs from SE as a whole, or does the convention stand?

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why a different rule should apply.

And when you are fixing a typo, removing greetings and signatures is common sense. It’s a minor edit, some may think it superfluous, I appreciate the effort.

If I am to venture a guess - the user in question has been a member for a comparatively  short time and no linked profiles to other sites. There’s a good chance that he simply didn’t know about the convention and combined with the fact that it takes some users a while to become comfortable with the fact that their posts may be edited by the community, the decline may well have been a knee-jerk protective reaction.

Comment: It should be noted that you had already applied the suggested edits.